# reach file within project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I am working on a website using JSP and Servlets. Instead of having a database, I want to have an XML file on my server. I want to save the information the user gives in the XML file within my project, which is saved under How can I define such a path in my code?

My Servlet is under `Project/src/servletPackage/myServlet.java` and the XML file is currently under `Project/WebContent/file.xml`. The path should **NOT** be such as: `C:/eclispe/workspace/Project/WebContent/file.xml`

This does work but only when the webpage is accessed from the main computer. On other computers, it creates a directory on the user's computer

Comment: *creates a directory on the user's computer*? This is a bit strange. Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to save the information the user gives in the XML file within my project

If that is what you want to do, then use

```
File infoFile = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/file.xml"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a classloader to access resources stored in your application classpath.
You can put your xml in WEB-INF/classes or other folder configured in your server as part of your classpath and use the method classLoader.getResourceAsStream to obtain an Inputflow to read the file.

[Here's and example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/loading-java-properties-files/) of how to load a properties file this way.

Notice that this solution only works if your servlet is deployed in one servler, if you work ni a cluster or multi-server enviroment these files will not be shared by servers.

If you need to share the files, put them in a shared folder and to avoid to hardcoding the absolute path in your code, use a servlet init parameter to point to the root of your storage folder, something like this.

```
<web-app>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServletName</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mycompany.MyServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name> storagefolder</param-name>
        <param-value>/var/opt/sun/appserver/sharedstoragefolder</param-value>
    </init-param>
    ...
</servlet>
...
</web-app>
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the XML in the classpath of your project and access to it as a ResourceStream. In eclipse, an easy way to do this is creating a package in your source code folder and adding there the file(s) you need:

```
Project
+ src
  + com.mycompany.bean
    - Bean1.java
    - Bean2.java
    ...
  + xml
    - file.xml
```

Accessing the file from Bean1 class

```
public class Bean1 {

    public void accessResourceFile() {
        InputStream xmlFile = Bean1.getClass().getResourceAsStream("xml/file.xml");
        //do what you want/need with the file...
    }
}
```

Another example:

- [Load resources as stream from class](http://www.java.happycodings.com/Other/code35.html)

Comment: The poster wants to save to the XML. If the generated classes and resources are bundled as a jar they are write-only.